# Line Chart with null values: How to keep Lines connected?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Im using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create charts on my webpage. Now i want to create combined charts with line and bar data. Since my line and bar data are independent from each other i need to use null values. For example:

```
x-labels: 08:00, 09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00
y-line: 12, null, 10, null, 15
y-bar: null, 25, null, 30, null
```

You can take this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9t0s429/1/) as an example. As you can see there, the line data are only dots, they are not connected with lines. I want those dots to be connected with lines. **How can i do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `beforeDatasetsDraw`

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
        for (dataset of chart.config.data.datasets) {
            for(data of dataset._meta[chart.id].data) {
                data._model.skip = false;
                data._model.tension = 0;
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `null` values try with '0', or the minimum value possible.

```
x-labels: 08:00, 09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00
y-line: 12, 0, 10, 0, 15
y-bar: 0, 25, 0, 30, 0
```

It is not able to process `null`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I googled the problem and there were people having the opposite problem of mine. so it has to be possible somehow. give 0 is not an option because null values should not be displayed at all.